# Creating a view from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql

I need to create a view named "testdisplay" that displays the author, article and article category.

I am having trouble creating a view to get the desired results, however. I have provided the details of the tables below:

```
DESCRIBE ArticleAuthors;                                                                       

 Field           Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra                                              

 AuthorCode      int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment                                     
 FirstName       varchar(100)    NO              NULL                                                           
 LastName        varchar(100)    NO              NULL                                                           
 EmailAddress    varchar(100)    NO              NULL                                                           
 Bio_Info        varchar(250)    NO              NULL                     


DESCRIBE Articles;
Field                Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra          

 ArticleCode         int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment 
 AuthorCode          int(11)         NO              NULL                       
 Title               varchar(100)    NO      MUL     NULL                       
 ShortDescription    varchar(250)    NO      MUL     NULL                       
 ArticleText         varchar(500)    NO      MUL     NULL                       
 date                date            NO              NULL    


DESCRIBE ArticleCategories;  

 Field                   Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra          

 ArticleCategoryCode     int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment 
 ArticleCode             int(11)         NO              NULL                       
 Category                varchar(100)    NO              NULL
```

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: And what are the desired results? Do we.. telepathically get to that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the view, then make querys from the view.

```
Create View `testdisplay` as 
Select
a.FirstName author, ar.Title article, c.Category Category
From
ArticleAuthors a
join Articles ar on ar.AuthorCode=a.AuthorCode
join ArticleCategories c on c.ArticleCode=ar.ArticleCode;
```

example of a select from the view:

```
select * from testdisplay where author = "your favorite author";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW testdisplay as
SELECT * FROM Articles art JOIN ArticleAuthors aut 
ON art.AuthorCode=aut.AuthorCode
JOIN ArticleCategories cat 
ON art.ArticleCode=cat.ArticleCode
```

Just replace * with the columns you need.